# MVC 4 OAuth: How to get e-mail address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I am developing an MVC 4 app and use the OAuth providers provided by MS, but I would like to get an e-mail address for every user. For Google (default) and Facebook (using FacebookClient) I already get the users address, but what to do about the following:

- Twitter (I have read it is not possible - still true?)
- *Microsoft - solved (see comments)*
- *Yahoo - works (see comment)*
- *LinkedIn - solved via own provider like for MS*

And what about, when it is not possible via OAuth like with Twitter?
I've read in different threads it is not good/secure to just ask the user for it. Is it "secure enough" if I also require a verification via e-mail to actually use the address (but not the account in general) as I (will) do when changing the address?

Comment: Not a complete answer so have it in a comment : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#user

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thanks for the tip - some follow up searches brought me to http://mvcdiary.com/2013/03/01/how-oauthsecurity-to-obtain-emails-for-different-oauth-clients-but-microsoft-client-doesnt-return-email-it-didnt-include-scope-wl-emails/ which solves the problem for Microsoft accounts...

Comment: Just found out, that Yahoo works "out of the box" IF you have a @yahoo.com address, which I hadn't before (just a yahoo account)...

Comment: Twitter still doesn't return emails, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of OAuth is not to provide email addresses, its to provide authentication in a standardized way. Just because a lot of the implementations also happen to give you the option of an email address doesn't mean that all of them must comply. Twitter is a case in point.

Why would asking a user for their email address not be "secure"?
I would question that, I mean if you can't trust a users input regarding their email address, what can you trust them with? If you're using some sort of confirmation mail system it would surely be fine?

Comment: "Not secure" in case of that the user could enter an invalid e-mail address, but when the OAuth-provider supplies it I can asume it is correct (and it is easier for the user not to enter it again). I already to it with confirmation for the other cases, but as said this is not as easy for the user...